# How can I enable it so that the axes of selected joints are visible?

Tags: rigging, joints, axes

I have enabled "Axes" in viewport display so I can see the axes of each individual joint but, whenever I select the tail joint, I cannot see the axes. I am referring to this, I took a screen grab of the tutorial I am following:
[image]

As you can see, when the joint is selected, the axes for the specific joint is displayed. I have gone through all possible settings yet I simply cannot see the axes. I've tried in both Blender 4.0 and earlier versions. I have also enabled "Axes" in "Data> Viewport Display."

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe the axes is at the head of the bone, check how the axes option is set. If it's not your problem please show a screenshot of your interface or share your file